# Kendo ui mvc grid doesn't working after update with a foreign column

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

i have 2 tables with relation one (table A) to many (table B)

i'd already made it working on update, delete, create with old data
my problem is when i add new data to table A and add new data to table B with ref to table A 
then grid is blank, i used firebug but i don't know how to fix it

**Controller**

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
 public ActionResult Update([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request, ReRoom room)
 {

 if (room != null && ModelState.IsValid) { var target = RoomRepository.One(p => p.PKiRoomID == room.PKiRoomID); if (target != null) 
{



  target.SDescription = room.SDescription;
 target.SRoomName = room.SRoomName; target.BStatus = room.BStatus;
 target.IRoomType = room.IRoomType; RoomRepository.Update(target); 
} 
} 
return Json(ModelState.ToDataSourceResult());
 }
```

**Repository**

```
public static void Update(ReRoom room)
 {
 ReRoom target = One(p => p.PKiRoomID == room.PKiRoomID); 
if (target != null)
 {
 target.SDescription = room.SDescription;
 target.SRoomName = room.SRoomName; 
target.BStatus = room.BStatus;
 target.IRoomType = room.IRoomType;
 } 
reModel rm = new reModel();
 var i = rm.ReRooms.Where(p => p.PKiRoomID == room.PKiRoomID).FirstOrDefault();
 if (i != null)
 {
 i.SDescription = room.SDescription;
 i.SRoomName = room.SRoomName;
 i.BStatus = room.BStatus;
 i.IRoomType = room.IRoomType;
 }
 rm.SaveChanges();
 }
```

**Index :**

```
columns.ForeignKey(p => p.IRoomType, (System.Collections.IEnumerable)ViewData["Types"], "ID", "Name");
 ViewData : private void populateRoomtypes() { ViewData["Types"] = new reModel().ReRoomTypes .Select(t => new { ID = t.PKiRoomTypeID, Name = t.SRoomTypeName }); 
}
```

Comment: Can you show us some code?

Comment: no please put the code into you question, and format it as such.